# How to avoid warning: Cannot setState on unmounted component? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, expo

im builiding a notebloc, so each time I go to the `Edit note screen` then go back, this warnings appears, heres the code:

when the app runs, the first component that rendes is Notes:

```
class Notes extends Component {
    
    state = {
        onpress: false,
        array_notes: [],
        selected_notes: [],
        update: false,
    }

    note = "";
    note_index = "";
    note_number = "";
    item_selected = 0;
    onpress = false;
 
    componentDidMount() {    
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => this.fetch_notes());
    }   
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._unsubscribe.remove();
    }

    fetch_notes = async() => {                  //fetch all the data
        const data = await fetch_notes();
        if (typeof data != "function") {
            this.setState({array_notes: data.array_notes});
        }else {
            data();
        }
    }
```

as you can see, in the `ComponentDidmount()` I run the function `fetch_data` to set the data, heres the `fetch_data function`:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

export const fetch_notes = async () => {
    try {
        const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("data"));
        if (data != null) {
            return data;
        }else {
            return () => alert("with no data");
        }
    }catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

here everything works, because its only fetch the data, now when I go to `edit note screen` and I edit one of the notes, I need to save it, so when I go back I need to fetch the data again so it will update:

```
save_changes = async() => {
    
    try {
    
        const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("data"));
        const index_to_find = this.array_notes.findIndex(obj => obj.note_number === this.note[0].note_number); 
   
        const edited_note = this.note.map((note) => {
            note.content = this.state.content;
            return {...note}
        });
   
        this.array_notes.splice(index_to_find, 1, edited_note[0]);
        data.array_notes = this.array_notes;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
     
    }catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
```

when I get back to `Notes screen` the function runs and works, the data are updated, but the warning still appears, once I saved the edit note and go back, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

This warning is thrown when you try to set the state of a component after it has unmounted.

Now, some things to point out here

- The navigation flow, from what have you mentioned is like `Notes` --> `Edit Notes` --> `Notes`. Assuming you are using the `StackNavigator` from `react-navigation`, the `Notes` screen **will not unmount** when you navigate to `Edit Notes` screen.
- The only screen unmounting is `Edit Notes` when you go back. So you should check the code to verify that you don't have any asynchoronous `setState` calls in that screen.

**P.S** : The syntax to remove the `focus` event listener is to just call the returned function as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener).
So in your `Notes` screen inside `componentWillUnmount` it should be

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use componentWillUnmount() function inside the function which you are unmounting.

You can use conditional rendering for mounting or unmounting any componets.

Comment: ?, dont understand very well what you are saying